# Unable to remove the python27 folder from windows which installed on 'c:/python27'

Tags: python-2.7

Installed python 2.7 interpreter on windows, in the folder `C:/Python27`. To get `pip` package, downloaded `get-pip.py` from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py following this post [How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows)

Executed the file `get-pip.py`, pip is installed, and uninstalled the python 2.7 interpreter, deleted the "Python27"  but unable to delete folder. Getting "you need permission to perform this action", you require permission from the computer's administrator to make changes to this folder `pip-1.5.6.dist-info`

When I tried installation again I'm getting error message like this:

"The installer has insufficient privileges to access the directory : The installation cannot continue".

Comment: Let me get this straight. You installed pip (successfully I believe), then you tried to **remove** `C:\Python27`? Why? That's where everything is installed! No wonder you're getting errors. What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Before I had tried to remove the python27 folder, I was uninstalled the python interpreter. Is I  have to uninstall pip before removing. If it is , could you tell how to uninstall the pip package.

Answer (score 0):

You must have run the `pip` installer using elevated privileges somehow. To delete a protected folder in Windows, right-click on the icon to open Windows Explorer, select "Run as Administrator", and enter your password if needed. You can now navigate to `C:\` and delete the `Python27` folder. I'm not in front of Windows at the moment, so the steps might be *slightly* different, but should be quite similar to what I've described.

Comment: when i tried like this , getting access denied error. Tried to change the owner ship of folder( it is empty) but getting access denied erros.

Comment: Are you sure you're in Admin mode? Go through the folder and delete the files one-by-one until you find the problematic ones. Look at their permissions, and change them as necessary. If you're **truly* an Administrator, you should be able to delete any file.